# Access to eks cluster with Lens issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, windows-subsystem-for-linux, amazon-eks, kubeconfig

I'm facing a problem whith Lens access to eks around 2 months ago.
I think I tried a lot of solutions but nothing is working for me.

I'm accessing to eks fine on wsl Ubuntu with AWS credentials.

I Installed the last version of Lens
put the kubeconfig file to add eks clusters
change the terminal to "wsl.exe" on Lens

And I have this error:

```
Starting connection ...

Authentication proxy started

Refreshing connection status ...

Unknown error has occurred
```

Have you faced this issue before? how did you solve it ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Might be helpful to tell us:
- which version of wsl.
- can you run kubectl commands using the same kubeconfig?